# Magento does not avoid duplicate emails registration

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am coding on Magento and I got a trouble with registration.
I don't know how and why to cause this issue.
An email address was created twice times as 2 accounts with 2 entity_id in the customer_entity table. I am using magento version 1.5

Example:

```
entity_id  | email          | created_at
495        | abch@gmail.com | 2013-10-19 09:47:01
496        | abch@gmail.com | 2013-10-19 09:47:03
```

In my customer_entity table, there are about over 1.000 records but there are about 30 records exists duplicating email like the example above

Please help me this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerObj = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    $customerObj->setWebsiteId($website->getId());
    $customerObj->loadByEmail($customer['email']);
    if ($customerObj->getId()) {
      $message = "duplicate found" ;
      return $message;
   }

}
```